# Perl script doesn't open command prompt on running in Windows7

Tags: perl

My Perl script doesn't execute at all when I press F5. In fact the command prompt also doesn't appear. Please help me as to what is wrong. The following is the Hello World script.

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello World!\n";
```

Comment: Where are you trying to run it?  What Perl installation do you have installed?

Comment: F5? In what program? F5 is "refresh" in explorer

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that your program runs so quickly that command prompt opens and closes faster than you can see it. To see if that's the case, and fix it if so, you can wait for user input:

```
print "Press ENTER to quit.\n";
scalar <>;
```